# Does the Searchable plugin work with Grails 2.0.0? (I argue no)

Tags: grails, searchable

When I upgrade to the project to grails 2.0 (with a fresh install of the searchable plugin), I get a Hibernate class cast exception. Does anybody else get this problem?

Comment: I'm using the searchable plugin in a Grails 2.0.0 app and it works fine. If you want some more useful assistance I suggest you post the relevant code

Comment: If you tell us you're getting an Exception it's pretty much a given that we're going to want to see the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

http://grails.org/ uses the Searchable plugin and it works with Grails 2.0.3. What issue are you running into?

Answer (score 1):

Searchable is based on [Compass](http://compass-project.org/) which is being rewritten as [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.com/).

The [ElasticSearch](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch) plugin works with Grails 2.0.

For more information see [The Future of Compass & ElasticSearch](http://www.kimchy.org/the_future_of_compass/).

Answer (score 1):

Migrating my app from Grails 1.3.7 to 2.1.1 ran into a similar issue. I was able to resolve it by updating the Searchable plugin from 0.5.5 to 0.6.4.

Here's what the stacktrace looked like:

```
| Error 2012-10-05 19:02:18,691 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryProxy cannot be cast to org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl
Message: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryProxy cannot be cast to org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl
Line 
| Method 
->>  95 | injectLifecycle in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.lifecycle.DefaultHibernateEntityLifecycleInjector
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    46 | injectLifecycle in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.lifecycle.DefaultHibernateEntityCollectionLifecycleInjector
|   149 | doStart . . . . in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDevice
|   125 | start           in org.compass.gps.device.AbstractGpsDevice
|    73 | start . . . . . in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.AbstractParallelGpsDevice
|   166 | start           in org.compass.gps.impl.AbstractCompassGps
|   144 | doCall . . . .  in SearchableGrailsPlugin$_closure3
|   303 | innerRun        in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask         in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . . . . . in     ''
^   680 | run             in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2012-10-05 19:02:18,715 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [localhost].[/myApp]  - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
Message: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryProxy cannot be cast to org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl
Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ClassCastException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryProxy cannot be cast to org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl
->>  95 | injectLifecycle in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.lifecycle.DefaultHibernateEntityLifecycleInjector
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    46 | injectLifecycle in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.lifecycle.DefaultHibernateEntityCollectionLifecycleInjector
|   149 | doStart  in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDevice
|   125 | start    in org.compass.gps.device.AbstractGpsDevice
|    73 | start .  in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.AbstractParallelGpsDevice
|   166 | start    in org.compass.gps.impl.AbstractCompassGps
|   144 | doCall . in SearchableGrailsPlugin$_closure3
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . .  in     ''
^   680 | run      in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes me too used searchable on grails 1.3.7 , 2.0.3 and now using on 2.1.1

All i have to do was upgrade my searchable plugin to the latest one. Though I had to made some tweaks in the code but every thing was mentioned in the plugin documentation

[link to documentation](http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+SearchableController+and+view)

Mind the imports in the controllers. As I guess the class path has been changed. And this was the only change I made.

Answer (score 0):

This happends because when you upgrade to a Grails version that uses Hibernate 4.X.
This happends because there were several package and class name changes between Hiberate 3.x and 4.x, so code that works with Hibernate 3.x won't work with 4.x except in rare cases. Beyond the name changes, there were big internal changes in how things work, so code that compiles won't necessarily run. App option #1 is to downgrade to Hibernate 3.x. The config settings for that are included and commented out (BuildConfig.groovy, DataSource.groovy), so this a very quick option. Obviously not an option if you depend on a feature added in 4.x, and this just delays the real problem until you have to upgrade Hibernate.